# Как работать с nvidia tesla p100 под ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, администрирование, cuda, nvidia

Здравствуйте. 
Хочу попробовать прогнать программу по работе с видео на компьютере с ubuntu 16.04 и видеокартой tesla p100. У tesla p100 нет видеовыхода, поэтому монитор подключен в еще одной установленной карте, простенькой nvidia gt 730. Проблема в том, что мне надо установить последнюю версию cuda и когда я произвожу установку, то такое чувство, что весь кудовский комплект (toolkit, дрова, opengl) пытает накатиться на nvidia gt 730,а не на tesla. Не совсем понятно, как с этим всем работать. В сети не нашел, как этой tesla p100 пользоваться. Через lspci linux видит tesla как 3d controller nvidia. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно накатить дрова и нормально со всем этим работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все предельно просто, переходишь на официальный сайт nvidia, вот тебе ссылка: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/118962/en-us
В терминале набираешь команду от рута: apt-get install cuda-drivers
Далее ребут, после ребута найди команду NVIDIA X Server Setting, открой ее, там отобразятся видеокарты Tesle p100 и geForce 730, удачи!